# webView No carga el resposive design

Tags: java, android, webview, webview-android

Saludos  mi gente  estoy asiendo esta app con ayuda de internet…..  Esta es la misma app en diferentes android oks  lo que sucede es que  en el virtual android  AVD  carga bien pero  en teléfono  no carga  el responsivo  de la web no eh descartado que sea  la web ya que  la pagina en el navegador de mi android  no carga con respsoive  podira ser mi androide   como daría soporte para que fuerce la pagina a cargar en resposive.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 package com.nextplena507.nextplena;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView = null;
    WebView view1;

    public MainActivity() {
        super();
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.view1 = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        WebSettings settings = view1.getSettings();
        view1.setInitialScale(1);
        view1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view1.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        view1.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        view1.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        view1.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        view1    .loadUrl("http://nextplena.com/home/descarga-musica/"); //try js alert
        //view.loadUrl("https://janisaacrc.wordpress.com/"); //try js alert
        view1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); // adding js alert support

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        view1.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(final String url, final String userAgent, final String contentDisposition, final String mimetype, final long contentLength) {
                final String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
                android.util.Log.d("Applog", "fileName:" + fileName);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                }
                request.setMimeType("audio/MP3");
                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, fileName);
                manager.enqueue(request);
            }


        });
    }

    public class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }


    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.view1.canGoBack()) {
            this.view1.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: A que te refieres con responsivo? deseas que se muestre exactamente como se ve en la imagen derecha?

Comment: Antes que todo hay que aclarar que el efecto responsivo se hace en el sitio, de manera que sea adaptable a cualquier dispositivo(android es uno de ellos). De hecho la forma en que te lo muestra el webview da a entender que tu sitio es responsivo, muestra de ello es el ícono 'burger'(Tres líneas horizontales del menú), si en tu teléfono te lo muestra diferente es porque tiene vistas para dimensiones diferentes.

Comment: Debes dar más detalles, al parecer el único problema es que en tu celular no carga la página por problemas de conectividad.

Comment: Que Tal Chicos Cierto.la vista depende de la web site lo que sucedía es que al lado derecho  usaba el emulador de nexus y a la izquierda mi j7 samsung entonces averigüé los User String Agents  esto lo que hace es decir a la pagina web en que tipo de navegador y tipo de dispositivo se carga entonces si la pagina web no tiene un buen viewport configurado si que le realice un trick engañándola web con user string de otro del setting  webview:webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android Nexus ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.111 Safari/537.36");